# JBOSSAS 7.1.1,jdbc6,Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection

Tags: oracle

```
Error while extracting database product name - falling back to empty error codes: org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:296) [org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:320) [org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory.getErrorCodes(SQLErrorCodesFactory.java:214) [org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.setDataSource(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:141) [org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.<init>(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:104) [org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.initExceptionTranslator(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:84) [mybatis-spring-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:70) [mybatis-spring-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:365) [mybatis-spring-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at $Proxy181.selectOne(Unknown Source)  at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectOne(SqlSessionTemplate.java:160) [mybatis-spring-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at com.orchestrall.domains.security.repository.mybatis.AccountRepositoryMyBatis.userAuthenticate(AccountRepositoryMyBatis.java:31) [classes:]
    at com.orchestrall.domains.security.impl.SecurityServiceImpl.userAuthenticate(SecurityServiceImpl.java:56) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319) [org.springframework.aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183) [org.springframework.aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) [org.springframework.aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110) [org.springframework.transaction-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [org.springframework.aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) [org.springframework.aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at $Proxy187.userAuthenticate(Unknown Source)   at com.orchestrall.web.security.UserSecurityController.userAuthenticate(UserSecurityController.java:52) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176) [org.springframework.web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [org.springframework.web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [org.springframework.web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112) [ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.2.0"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146) [ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.2.0"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208) [ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.2.0"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.getMetaData(PhysicalConnection.java:1517) [ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.2.0"]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.getMetaData(DelegatingConnection.java:345) [commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.getMetaData(PoolingDataSource.java:245) [commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:285) [org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 53 more
```

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Just posting an error message and a stack trace makes it difficult to determine what your question is. Please provide some context, and only the relevant parts of the stack trace.